# BigQuery - Auto Schema - Look at more than 100 rows

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I am currently looking to load data into Google BigQuery, however due the large number of columns I am looking to use the AutoSchema functionality.  The issue I am having is that the data may have 500 integer values in a field, followed by a string as the 501st value, meaning the autoschema (having only read the first 100 rows) defines this field to be an integer (and then fails the upload for the non-integer value).  Usually I would choose to define these columns manually but this would be time consuming given the large number of files I have (and large number of columns in each)

I am using a rest API to post JSON into Google to build these tables, but was wondering if there is a way to set BigQuery to scan more than 100 rows in the autodetect schema functionality?

Comment: What's the problem? 100 rows is used to detect schema but you can have more columns. Don't be confused of the 100 rows is not 100 columns. Try it out.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have edited the question to make it clearer.  The issue is with the type of columns for the autoschema, rather than the number of columns, as the type is defined by looking at the first 100 rows

Comment: Grab one small sample from any of your files which have the desired schema length and only use that to auto schema. Once the schema is ready you load the other files.

Comment: I agree with Pentium10: from what I understand you have to select a representative sample for your auto-detection.

Comment: Additionally can you clarify: are you reading data with 501 columns, but first 100 rows don't have the last 501st, which causes an exception?

Comment: I have had similar issues when trying to use the auto schema of BigQuery (with CSV, instead of JSON). Have you tried the Avro format? The BigQuery schema will be directly taken from your Avro schema. So it works way better for me.